# OGR Foreign Data Wrappers

Tags: postgis, postgresql, ogr-fdw

I had created a foreign server in the E drive with a data source of "e:/files/" for Map info tab files.
It was all working well until I had to refresh or re-create the server. It gave an "unable to connect to data source" error. I have added the image for reference.

**Query:**

```
CREATE Extension ogr_fdw;
create Server fileserver
 foreign data wrapper ogr_fdw
 options (datasource 'e:/files/', format 'mapInfo File');
```

**Error:**

[image]

I have already created servers on other drives too. And I suppose there is a problem with creating the foreign server on the same drive again.
And I have tried restarting the PostgreSQL service, but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Try without the trailing `/`.

Comment: i have already tried that. It doesn't work.

Comment: Check if the user running the database (probably "postgres") has full access (read and write) to the file folder.